# Get most/least sold items in C# datatable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, linq-to-objects, subquery

I-m creating a C# WPF application that lets a user take orders (think restaurant/bar).

For simplicity, I'm restricting orders into simple purchases of individual items (you can buy multiple items, like buying 4 beers). Each purchase is logged as a Purchase object:

```
class Purchase
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public DateTime time {get;set;}
    public double price {get;set;}
    public int quantity {get;set;}
}
```

and each purchase gets added to a DataTable.

I want to get the 3 most - and 3 least bought items in a given time and I'm having trouble writing a suitable query for this.

So far what I have is this but it's not working:

```
 public List<int> GetMostBought()
    {
        DateTime lastMinute = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(new TimeSpan(0, -1, 0)); //one minute ago
        int howMany = 3; // how many items to get.
        var query =
           (from p in purchases.AsEnumerable()
            where p.Field<DateTime>("time")>= lastMinute //purchases made less than a minute ago
            select new { Product = p, Quantity = p.Field<int>("quantity") } into productQty
            group productQty by productQty.Product into pg
            let totalQuantity = pg.Sum(prod => prod.Quantity)
            orderby totalQuantity descending
            select pg.Key).Take(howMany);

        List<int> mostBoughtIDs = new List<int>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in query)
        {
            mostBoughtIDs.Add(Int32.Parse(dr[0].ToString()));
        }
        return mostBoughtIDs;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var mostBoughtIDs = purchases.AsEnumerable()
                             .Where(r=>r.Field<DateTime>("time")>= lastMinute)
                             .GroupBy(r=>r.Field<int>("id"))
                             .OrderByDescending(g=>g.Sum(r=>r.Field<int>("quantity"))
                             .Select(g=>g.First().Field<int>("id"))
                             .Take(howMany);
```

Comment: I get a "'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'id' and no extension method 'id' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRow' could be found" error on the select line (at .id) Is something else missing?

Comment: is there a column called "id" in your datatable? We are assuming that your DataTable reflects the object you defined.

Comment: @ConnorU only the `Where` can affect that, you should be sure `lastMinute` has proper value so that the filtered result should contain at least 1 item.

Comment: I finally caught it, I was using UTC now for one time and basic Now for the other.
Thanks for everything! Your code runs now, ther-es a bug I-m tyring to figure out but I can handle it.

Answer (score 1):

taking that into account, my answer is nearly identical to king kings...

```
var items = 
    purchases.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(e => e.Field<DateTime>("time") >= lastMinute)
    .GroupBy( g => g.Field<int>("id") )
    .OrderByDecending( i => i.Sum( e => e.Field<int>("quantity") ) )
    .Select( g => g.First().Field<int>("id"))
    .Take(3)
```

Comment: Oh, I should have removed that comment, I am using the quantity field and more importantly, I want the query to be able to handle quantities for future regardless. Thanks anyway

Comment: Your answer returns an empty list, as does KingKing's :/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DataTable from a List with a nice little method found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6ffcb247-77fb-40b4-bcba-08ba377ab9db/converting-a-list-to-datatable):

```
public DataTable ConvertToDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties =
           TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;

    }

public List<int> GetMostAndLeastBought(int howMany){
List<Purchase> purchasesList = new List<Purchase>{
                                            new Purchase{ id = 1, time = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, -1)), quantity = 1},
                                            new Purchase{id = 1, time = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, -1)), quantity = 1},
                                            new Purchase{id = 2, time = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, -1)), quantity = 1},
                                            new Purchase{id = 2, time = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, -1)), quantity = 1},
                                            new Purchase{id = 3, time = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, -1)), quantity = 1},
                                            new Purchase{id = 3, time = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, -1)), quantity = 1},
                                            new Purchase{id = 4, time = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, -1)), quantity = 1},
                                            new Purchase{id = 4, time = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, -1)), quantity = 1},
                                            new Purchase{id = 5, time = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, -1)), quantity = 1},
                                            new Purchase{id = 6, time = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, -1)), quantity = 1},
                                            new Purchase{id = 7, time = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, -1)), quantity = 1}                                                                              
                                        };

        DataTable purchases = ConvertToDataTable(purchasesList);
```

I thought the query syntax also works nicely here for the main query:

```
 DateTime lastMinute = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(new TimeSpan(0, -1, 0)); //one minute ago  

var query = from p in purchases.AsEnumerable()
            where p.Field<DateTime>("time") >= lastMinute
            group p by p.Field<int>("id") into g                    
            select new {Id = g.Key, TotalQuantity = g.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("quantity"))} into s
            orderby s.TotalQuantity descending, s.Id
            select s.Id;
```

You can then get most and least at the same if you wanted to at the same time. You want to convert List before doing both because then you can efficiently get the last elements, like so:

```
var list = query.ToList();

var most = list.GetRange(0, howMany);
var least = list.GetRange(list.Count - howMany, howMany);
```